# How to merge two data.frame using index list in R?

Tags: r

Lets say we have two data frames: A:

```
COl1    COL2
1,2...  Hello
3       World
```

where every element in COL1 is a vector of number.
and B:

```
WAHHH
Danny
Bob
Nice
```

is there a easy way which I can make them turn into this:

```
WAHHH COL2
Danny Hello
Bob   Hello
Nice  World
```

Thank you so much

Comment: My general advice would be not to store unnormalized indices `1:2` as you are doing.  It will make all data manipulation much harder down the road.

Comment: theres a mistake in my discription. Sorry about that. The way it is stored is a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can split the 'COl1' in 'A' dataset, convert to `numeric`, get the sequence, set the names of the `list` elements with 'COL2', `stack` to convert to 2 column `data.frame` and `cbind` with the second dataset

```
cbind(B, setNames(stack(setNames(lapply(strsplit(A$COl1, ":"), 
      function(x) Reduce(`:`, as.numeric(x))), A$COL2))[2], "COL2"))
#  WAHHH  COL2
#1 Danny Hello
#2   Bob Hello
#3  Nice World
```

#### Update

If "COl1' is stored as a `list`

```
cbind(B, setNames(stack(setNames(A$COl1, A$COL2))[2], "COL2"))
#  WAHHH  COL2
#1 Danny Hello
#2   Bob Hello
#3  Nice World
```

---

Or use `rep` with `lengths`

```
data.frame(B, COL2=rep(A$COL2, lengths(A$COl1)))
#  WAHHH  COL2
#1 Danny Hello
#2   Bob Hello
#3  Nice World
```

NOTE: If 'COl1' is `factor` class, use `strsplit(as.character(A$COl1), ":")`l

Comment: theres a mistake in my discription. Sorry about that. The way it is stored is a list.